# Adding self-signed SSL certificate to a ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https

Hi I am new to trying to implement HTTPS on a local development project. I am trying to add a self signed SSL certificate to a react project running locally using this guide. https://www.makeuseof.com/create-react-app-ssl-https/

I have managed to create the cert and cert-key files in the root folder and added the following to my start script:

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=./localhost.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=./localhost-key.pem react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},

However when I start the project with npm start, the web site is using a different SSL certificate found inside node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem

I have tried deleting the server.pem but it generates a new certificate when I run 'npm start'. Changing the content of the server.pem file to match my self-signed certificated works, but I was wondering why my start script does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of `react-scripts` do you use? According to their [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/), using https is supported from `react-scripts@0.4.0` and higher.

Comment: hi, i am running on 2.1.5